# How to get the same layout dimensions for all iPhones in my sprite kit game Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

This is the code the set the layout for my game the problem is that when my game is play on a smaller version phone the layout changes how do i keep the same dimensions 
Code:

```
 override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        let sKView = self.view! as! SKView
        sKView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.size = sKView.bounds.size
        let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.45)
        sKView.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)



  }

}
```

The code above doesn't work well it does but only for iPhone 6 plus which is the iPhone I'm test my application with but it doesn't change dimensions when on smaller iPhones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I'm aware of is to manually resize and move nodes based on screen size, for example:

```
if size.width == 320 && size.height == 568 {
//iPhone 5/5S screen dimensions
spriteNode!.size = CGSize(height: 30, width: 45)
spriteNode!.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50)
} else if size.width == 768 && size.height == 1024 {
//iPad screen dimensions
spriteNode!.size = CGSize(height: 60, width: 90) /* Twice the normal size */
spriteNode!.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 80) /* Moved over and above a bit */
}
```

It's a pain in the neck, but AFAIK it's the easiest way to resize nodes to fit different screen sizes.

Comment: Why you don't use `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` for detect screen size. Set the spriteNode constraint with the ratio.

Comment: Thanks but What would the code ratio look like and would i simply just type in UIScreen.mainScreen

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd usually go about this is as follows: when creating the scene, I will set the size to specific defaults based on the device; eg: for landscape only mode (sizes are just for example):

```
    let size =
    UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad ?
        CGSizeMake(3200, 2400) : // all ipads, 4:3 ratio
        UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.landscapeSize().width < 568 ?
            CGSizeMake(2400, 1600) : // iphone 4s rows; 3:2 ratio
            CGSizeMake(2850, 1600) // other iphones 16:9 ratio
```

This allows me to have known sizes for the scene on any device.

To layout UI elements, I use the scene size and use offsets, so a button at the top left will have coordinates `(0, scene.height)` (for a sprite anchored to `(0,1)`), and that button will always appear on the top left of any scene in any device.

It is usually better to have a node hiearchy in your scene

- Scene

  - BackgroundNode: SKNode, zPosition = 0
  - WorldNode: SKNode, zPosition = 10
  - HudNode: SKNode, zPosition = 20

This will allows you to zoom in / zoom out on the world node (which contain gameplay elements) while keeping UI elements (buttons) in the HUD node a fixed size.

To zoom in/out you modify the worldNode scale directly, for example `scene.worldNode.setScale(scaleAmount)`. (assuming you are not using SKCameraNode)

This scheme will allow you to not have to position/resize individual sprites for each device; rather changes are done at the root level - in this case the worldNode, and also allows you to have UI elements that more or less scale appropriately based on device, and remain fixed independent of your worldNode scale.